# What are the best possible ways to integrate a Front End(Vue) and Backend(Django-DRF) for a web application?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

What are the best possible ways to integrate a Front End(Vue) and Backend(Django-DRF) for a web application ?

Comment: please give us more details. What do you mean in integrating? like, it's obvious that if you are using vue drf will play nicer than bare django.

Comment: Sorry for that,I mean that,should i use drf APIs or bare Django? What are the pros and cons of using drf APIs ,over just using bare Django.

Comment: https://www.techiediaries.com/django-angular-cli/  check that out.  its angular, but the concepts can be easily applied to vue

Comment: Choose the option you are confortable with. DRF adds a lot of things with little effort for the most commun use cases but requires to learn a few more things.

Answer (score 1):

[Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) has many features with simple settings for request and response handling.
You can use JSON data format to connect to DRF. It has an authentication system ([TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) and [JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) authentication).

The Django REST framework is a powerful and flexible toolkit for building web APIs. Serialization that supports both ORM and non-ORM data sources.

If you're using Django, you'll need to define your own authentication system, and you'll need to have serialize methods to create response  data.

Vuejs request modules ([Axios](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html?redirect=true), ...) are compatible with json format and easy to connect to REST API services.

You need only Management "Cross-Origin Resource" in Backend with
[django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

```
# settings.py

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
   "https://example.com",
   "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
]
```

You easily configure DRF and Vuejs completely. Request permissions can be checked with "token authentication".
For example :
Keep backend token in LocalStorage and send token in Headers request with simple settings in axios. DRF checks it and handles permissions like "IsAuthenticated".

```
// axios config files

axios.interceptors.request.use(
(config) => {
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`;
    }
})
```

DRf is a good suggestion for communication between Frontend and Backend .